# Terminal exits after reaching pushback statement in c++

Tags: c++, data-structures

I tried to get input and construct tree using a function named `inputtree()`. My function doesn't work the way I expect even though it's seems to be correct.

```
template <typename t>class tree{
public:
    t data;
    vector<tree<t>*>children;
    tree(){
    }
    tree(t data){
        this->data=data;
    }
};
void inputtree(tree<int>*root){
    int element;
    cin>>element;
    root->data=element;
    int size;
    cin>>size;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        int element;
        cin>>element;
        tree<int>*chumma=new tree<int>(element);

        root->children.push_back(chumma);
        cout<<"Statement not reached"<<element<<endl;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<root->children.size();i++){
        inputtree(root->children[i]);
    }
}
int main(){
    tree<int>*sample;
    inputtree(sample);
}
```

`root->children.push_back` causes error. How to fix it?

Comment: You never constructed your ```sample``` object that is passed to ```inputtree``` by pointer. You just passed a pointer of type ```tree<int>``` to your function while you MUST call *tree* constructor first and then pass it to your function.

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh why exactly we need to do that? I could access `data` element from the tree class, similarly I can also access vector right?

Comment: @KharinandanDN In `root->data` you dereference `root` but, what object does `root` point at? `sample` is uninitialized so reading from it makes the program have undefined behavior

Comment: You access members, data, and methods of a **class** while they are laid at a memory place. Instantiation means allocating needed memory for these data. When you did not instantiate your object, there is no memory place to take care of ```data``` for you.

Comment: The overall problem here is a very common one in C++. It even has a name: "Pointless Use Of Pointers". A careful review of the shown code finds no reason to use any pointers. The entire logic should be reimplemented, from scratch without any pointers. Problem solved. It's important to learn about pointers and how they work, in order to understand when ***not*** to use them.

Comment: s/exists/exits/ ??  It's not at all clear to me how the title of the question is related to the question.  What does the behavior of the terminal have to do with the programming error you describe?  I could guess this means you are executing your code in some system which spawns a terminal for the purpose of executing your code, and the termination of that terminal is the event you are witnessing that indicates premature termination of your program, but that is pure speculation.

Comment: 'My function doesn't work the way I expect even though it's correct.' is a contradiction in terms. Make up your mind. Either your expectations are wrong or your function is.

Comment: Without pointers, it could be simplified into [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Y83Kc5Yc4)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you so much for clearing the doubt.

Comment: @WilliamPursell You're speculation is right. I was running my program in codeblocks. Sorry for not being clear. Can you please suggest me a way to edit this question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
template <typename T>
class tree { 
    T data; 
    vector<tree<T>&> children;
public:
    tree()
    { 
        data = T(); 
    }
    tree(const T& _data) : data {_data}
    { 
    } 
};


int main()
{
    tree <int> MyTree(42);
    // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: How does this address the original problem from the question?

Comment: @ComicSansMSWhen the building blocks are wrong, it does not make any sense to go more into detail. He said ```I constructed tree ...``` while this is not true. I tried to make it clear first.